# Log scale density coloring for geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

The `geom_hex` geometry in `ggplot2` colors hexagonal bins according to the number of points falling within them. This works pretty well for uniformly distributed data, but not so well if some regions are way more dense than others-- differences can get drowned out by the presence of a single very dense hexagon.

How can I make the density color scale use a log scale or some other kind of normalizing transformation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**ggplot** 3.0+ demystifies the calculation of summary metrics via the new `stat()` internal function. This makes it easier to modify the statistic being used to create the fill for the hexes. So for example:

### Default count statistic

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000),
  y = rnorm(1000)
)

plot.df <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex(aes(fill = stat(count)))
print(plot.df)
```

[image]

### Log count statistic

```
plot.df.log <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex(aes(fill = stat(log(count))))
print(plot.df.log)
```

[image]

In place of `log`, you could do any arbitrary transformation you want, like cube root, etc.

### Using `cut`

To avoid creating a scale with confusing values, you could use `cut` to establish sensible category boundaries, and convert these to a numeric scale which is labeled with the original count values:

```
plot.df.log.cut <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex(aes(fill = stat(cut(log(count), breaks = log(c(0, 1, 2, 4, Inf)), labels = F, right = T, include.lowest = T)))) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = 'count', labels = c('1', '2', '4', '8+'))
print(plot.df.log.cut)
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the solution with `cut` but shouldn't the legend be discrete and not continuous?

Comment: Since `cut` is called with `labels = F`, the resulting bins will be numeric, and can be treated as continuous for plotting. But one certainly could have done discrete coloring.

Comment: My point is: since you only have discrete values, a continuous legend is rather misleading. Removing `labels = F` and using `scale_fill_discrete` would provide a more understandable plot IMO.